# How can I replace a line with user input?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I need to do this prompts in a function. Can someone please help me? I just don't understand how. I'm just a beginner.

This should be written in a function.

- Prompt for two line numbers, one is the starting line of text to copy, and the second is the end line of the text to copy. Slice this part of the list, and add it to the end of the list as a single string.Check that the line numbers entered are valid. If they are invalid, ask for a line numbers again.
- Prompt for a line number and then replace that line with a new one from the user. Check that the line number entered is valid. If it is invalid, ask for a line number again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton to get you started. Use the `input` builtin function to get user input and check if they are valid in a `while` loop

```
def isValid(start, end):
    # Check if your start and end numbers are value here
    return start <= end

def getUserInput():
    start = 0
    end = -1
    while True:
        start = input("Enter starting line number: ")
        end = input("Enter ending line number: ")
        if not isValid(start, end):
            print("Invalid input, try again")
        else:
            break

    ## Do what you want with the list here
    return start, end
```

Comment: Oh I see, i'll try that. Also, I have been working on adding a lines when a command is called. So for example, my input is a which will add a line and then d which will delete a line but everytime I call q which will quit the whole program it doesn't work.